# Can I start a new single-player Ark game and save the old one?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

I love my current Ark Survival Evolved game, but I would love to start a new single-player game. Is there anyway I can start a new Ark single-player game and save the old one. 
P.S., this has to be on the Island, not on Scorched Earth or the Center.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes, if you were to backup your save game data to USB storage.

Comment: It doesn't need to be USB storage. You can copy the save game folder anywhere, even within the same folder the original save folder is in, just rename it. - I save mine in `d:\backups\Ark` for example, which is on the same drive I have the game installed, copying it after every single game to ensure I have a none corrupted backup. I play several different maps simultaneously that way without problems, just swapping out save folders.